# Find Method name from SOAP Request

Tags: java, soap

I have SOAP request XML, I want to find the method name from it. I used the following code, but the SOAP Body always stating null, If I got Soap Body, then the imediate next child will be the Method name. How to solve this?

```
String xml1 = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"+
 "<soap:Body>"+
"<ConversionRate xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">"+
  "<FromCurrency>AFA</FromCurrency>"+
  "<ToCurrency>TRY</ToCurrency>"+
"</ConversionRate>"+
"</soap:Body>"+
"</soap:Envelope>";

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml1.getBytes());
SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
System.out.println(body);
```

Comment: Found the answer.

    body.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName()

This will give the Method name.

Comment: great, please post it as an answer, and accept it - that will mark the question as closed and help future viewers to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
       body.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName()
```

This will give the Method name